# Close file after LinkFormat.Update

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint presentation which has several Charts and Linked Worksheet Ojects all from Excel and from multiple files.  I am using the code below to update all of the charts/objects in the presenation as they change on a daily basis.  The code works for the job; however, after it runs I am left with several "open" excel files that are not visible.  The only way I know they are open is if I open as separate excel file and close it, I will then be asked if I want to save all of the other files that were used to update my PowerPoint.  How do I ensure that each of the files used to update the presentation are closed (without saving)?  I know how to close each document one by one in the code by putting in the file path but if possible I would like a way that will work for any new charts/objects as well so the code doesn't need updated.

```
Sub updatelinks()
Dim sld As Slide, shp As Shape

For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        On Error Resume Next
        shp.LinkFormat.Update
    Next
Next
MsgBox "All Charts Updated"
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for  your help, and by the way, I am new at this so open to any suggestions that would make my original code better.  Also, I am using Office 365 if that matters.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

You say you know how to close excel files with the file path so I wont bore you with those details, but you can get the file path of the excel file used to update with `shp.LinkFormat.SourceFullName`, so you can use that in your loop to close them after each update.